# Why are there rivets on the drum case of a band brake

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, mechanical

Ive seen some images of band brakes and I notice there are usually two rivets (or screws) on the drum casing (encircled in the image below). What are the rivets riveted to? And why are they riveted?
Are these rivets present only in simple band brakes or are they also present in other types of drum brakes?

[image: Band brake]

*Image from Wikipedia. Usage licence: CC BY-SA 3.0*

Answer (score 3):

The circled portions of the image provided are not rivets. They are locking adjustment screws. According to information provided in an [answer (number 2) on the bicycles stack exchange](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8456/how-can-i-stop-a-belt-brake-band-brake-from-squealing), the primary purpose of those screws is to provide a uniform gap between the brake band and the drum when the brake lever is released.

There is one long rivet in the 4 o'clock position securing the band from rotating and another rivet in the 3 o'clock position at which point the actuating lever is attached. Those with digital time keeping devices, disregard the above references.